# Doubts about proof of completeness of finite-dimensional normed spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Every $n$-dimensional normed space $X$ (over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$) is complete.

Let $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ be a basis for $X$ and define the norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $X$ by $\|x\|=\max_{i\leqslant n}|\alpha_i|$ whenever $x=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ie_i$. We take a Cauchy sequence $(x_k)$. Since all $x\in X$ can be written as a unique linear combination of $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$, we write $x_k=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha^k_i e_i$ for each $k\in\mathbb N$ and given $\varepsilon>0$, we know that there is $N$ such that $$ k,m\geqslant N\implies\|x_k-x_m\|=\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n\big(\alpha_i^k-\alpha_i^m\big)e_i\right\|=\max_{i\leqslant n}\big|\alpha_i^k-\alpha_i^m\big|<\varepsilon.$$ Then, for fixed $i\leqslant n$, we have $\big|\alpha_i^k-\alpha_i^m\big|<\varepsilon$ for $k,m\geqslant N$, i.e. $\big(\alpha_i^k\big)_{k\geqslant 1}$ is a Cauchy sequence in the complete space $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$) and thus converges to some $\alpha_i\in\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$) for each $i\leqslant n$. Set $x=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ie_i$ and let $m\to\infty$ in the above displayed equation so that $$k\geqslant N\implies \|x_k-x\|=\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n\big(\alpha_i^k-\alpha_i\big)e_i\right\|=\max_{i\leqslant n}\big|\alpha_i^k-\alpha_i\big|.$$

---

At this point, my notes say that that the right-hand side above is $\leqslant \varepsilon$, instead of $<\varepsilon$. In general as I see it we have that there are $N_i$ such that $\big|\alpha_i^k-\alpha_i\big|<\varepsilon$ whenever $k\geqslant N_i$ for each $i\leqslant n$. Thus, for $k\geqslant \max_i N_i$ we have $\|x_k-x\|=\max_{i\leqslant n}\big|\alpha_i^k-\alpha_i\big|<\varepsilon$. But again, it is $<\varepsilon$, not $\leqslant \varepsilon$.

1. Why do we have to include the possibility of equality with $\varepsilon$;
2. Can we not bypass all this by writing $\lim_{k\to\infty}\|x_k-x\|=\lim_{k\to\infty}\max_{i\leqslant n}\big|\alpha_i^k-\alpha_i\big|=0$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adressing the third point, $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ie_i$ is a linear combination of elements in $X$. Since $X$ is a vector space, the linear combination stays in $X$.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Thanks, you are right, that was trivial!